# Manually define "where clause" of a seed features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, featuretools

When using `ft.dfs` to get feature definitions, the `where_primitives` parameter filters values based on interesting variables of an entity. Is it possible to also manually define the "where clause" of a seed feature?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to manually define a where clause for any seed feature based on an aggregation primitive using the `where` parameter.

Let’s say you wanted define “count the number of transaction by a customer where the amount was greater than 15”. You could do the following:

```
import featuretools as ft
from featuretools.primitives import Count, NumTrue
es = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)
print(es)
```

```
Entityset: transactions
  Entities:
    customers (shape = [5, 3])
    sessions (shape = [35, 4])
    products (shape = [5, 2])
    transactions (shape = [500, 5])
  Relationships:
    transactions.product_id -> products.product_id
    transactions.session_id -> sessions.session_id
    sessions.customer_id -> customers.customer_id
```

We could then define the where clause as follows:

```
greater_15 = ft.Feature(es['transactions']['amount']) > 15
count_greater_15 = Count(es['transactions'][‘transaction_id’],
                         parent_entity=es[‘customers’],
                         where=greater_15)
```

First, we create a boolean feature that determines if the transaction amount is greater than 15. Then, we use the `Count` primitive and specify the where clause. Behind the scenes, Featuretools removes any rows where the where feature evaluates to false before calculating `Count`.

Now we are ready to calculate the feature:

```
fm = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(features=[count_greater_15],
                                 instance_ids=[1, 2, 3])
print(fm)
```

```
             COUNT(transactions WHERE amount > 15)
customer_id
1                                              121
2                                              112
3                                               72
```

To verify this did what we expected, let’s use the `NumTrue` primitive which counts the number of True values. We can see it is equivalent to `count_greater_15`

```
num_greater_15 = NumTrue(greater_15, parent_entity=es["customers"])
fm = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(features=[num_greater_15],
                                 instance_ids=[1, 2, 3])
print(fm)
```

```
             NUM_TRUE(transactions.amount > 15)
customer_id
1                                           121
2                                           112
3                                            72
```